# Java Vector/List Element Removal

Tags: java, list, vector, addition, element

Hi I have 2 quick questions regarding Java Vector element removal.

1. How do I remove an element from my vector
2. If I remove an element from the vector in my object and I then GSON my object to a JSON file will the element be absent from the json file? Or will the removed element still be in the json file?

This is the code:

```
public class Activities {
    private String instanceID;
    private String tripID;
    public List<ActivitySensor> acts;
    private String gout;

    public Activities() {
        acts = new Vector<ActivitySensor>(3, 3);
    }
    // etc
    // etc
}

public class ActivitySensor {
    private String name;
    private int typeID;
    private int confidence;
    private Date beginTime;
    // etc
    // etc
}
```

I instantiate as follows:

```
ActivitySensor act;
Activities activities = new Activities();
act = new ActivitySensor();
```

Then when I want a new set of elements added to ActivitySensor I do this...

```
activities.acts.add(act);
```

All of the above is working. Here's the problem...
    As I am processing and learn something new about the above act object adds, I sometimes want to remove some act entries.

So I do this

```
activities.acts.remove(act);
```

I get no errors but after the next step it appears they are not really deleted.

When I am done processing, I GSON the activities object. The json file contains all act elements, even those I deleted. Therefore, does remove element REALLY remove the element or just set a flag somewhere? Or, am I approaching this the wrong way and my remove is not really working as I expect?

Comment: Could you remove or comment out the `etc` lines so that this code compiles? Thanks.

Comment: It should return true if the element is removed successfully. You can check the size of vector if it changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - How do I remove an element from my vector

Doing the way you've done here in this code, i.e., by calling [`public boolean remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) OR [`public E remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#remove(int)) method.

`activities.acts.remove(act);` should work fine somewhere after `activities.acts.add(act);` and before the conversion of the object into JSON. I doubt the step where you're calling this! Have you really converted it into JSON after removing the element?

Also, try storing the output of the remove statement into a boolean variable.

```
boolean isRemoved = activities.acts.remove(act);
```

> **public boolean remove(Object o)**
>
> **Removes the first occurrence of the specified element** in this Vector.
>   **If the Vector does not contain the element, it is unchanged**. More
>   formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that
>   (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element
>   exists).

---

> 2. If I remove an element from the vector in my object and I then GSON my object to a JSON file will the element be absent from the json
>      file? Or will the removed element still be in the json file?

If you GSON your object to a JSON file **after removal of the vector element from the object**, it will, for sure, be absent from the JSON file. As simple as anything and, as expected.

Also, I'd suggest you to see through a debugger.

Comment: Yes sir you are very helpful :P

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found the problem. I was instantiating act before the remove statement. I have rearranged and it is now working.

Comment: Before the fix I called: act = new ActivitySensor(); just before the remove. Therefore all the remove was doing was removing a brand new act and not the act I wanted to remove. Therefore I move the remove statement to just before the act = new statement and all is well. Hope this helps.